# How to transfer data from multiple columns to just one column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to bring all these values in columns, for just one column. I need a matrix range like this, for example: {29,28,25,11,20,21,16,13,15,10,23 ,, 9,22,0,21,12 ,,, 21 , 25} etc ... and so on, how do you do this? I tried to do with the formula "Transpose ()" but it didn't work, is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104710/discussion-on-question-by-elienay-junior-how-to-transfer-data-from-multiple-colu).

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple formula in your cell (`B9` in your example) which uses `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(x,y))` where `x` and `y` are the positions of the data you need to get. In your case, it would start at `(1,1)`.

*(As noted by Scott Craner in a comment, you probably want to use `INDEX()` instead of `INDIRECT()`).*

The `x` position is going to increment from 1 to n and then repeat. So you can use the `MOD()` function to do that. In our case the `ROW()` is the number we need to use. Since `MOD()` is zero based, you have to do a little bit of math, nothing major:

```
MOD(ROW() - 9, 1000) + 1
```

- The '-9' is because we start on row 9. In your case, if you have 2,000 rows, it will be closer to 2,000, of course. The number must become 0 in the very first entry.
- The 1,000 is the number of columns you have in your spreadsheet.

For the `y` position, you use an integer division (i.e. a `FLOOR()`). Again, the `ROW()` starts at 1, so we need to take that in account.

```
FLOOR((ROW() - 9) / 1000) + 1
```

- The '-9' and 1,000 are like above.

Now we have a complete formula:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MOD(ROW() - 9, 1000) + 1, FLOOR((ROW() - 9) / 1000) + 1))
```

First verify that this works as expected for the first cell (i.e. `B9`) then try again for the next few cells (`B10`, `B11`) by copying the line (i.e. select `B9` and N number of lines after that and then hit <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>). You should test enough cells so you start seeing the second line appearing in your new column.

Now select `B9` and all the rows to copy the entire set of values vertically (so if you have 1,000 columns × 2,000 rows, you need 2,000,000 rows in that column, not too sure Excel goes that far, though)

This will copy the data vertically. If necessary, you could do that in a separate sheet instead of below the existing data. Up to you. When referencing rows, it needs to include the name of the sheet. I'm not too sure how to do that with `ADDRESS` but you can probably find the info in the docs. At this point, though, this is formulae and not just plain data. If you want to convert that column to plain data, save it in a CSV file where formulae do not get saved. Then reload the CSV and copy that column where you want it.

Done without VBA. (although formulae are kind of VBA expressions...)

Comment: One note, INDIRECT is Volatile and too many will slow down the calcs.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah, the last paragraph is about saving the sheet in a CSV and reloading that. That way the formula goes away.

Comment: Use INDEX instead and then it is not Volatile and can remain.  I misread the question and thought the OP wanted to skip the blanks.

Comment: though, I do think that the blank cells will become `0` with this and not remain blank

Comment: I had used "Offset ()" to do this, although it worked, I had to use some auxiliary columns, leaving the spreadsheet with more content

Comment: @ElienayJunior OFFSET is also volatile, be careful using too many of them.